# Django/Python url regex with dash

Tags: python, regex, django

I am trying to create a url with regex settings to allow for all job numbers that are just numeric values, have dashes or that start/contain a letter.

My url originally was:

```
url(r'^jobs/(?P<job_number>\w+)/$', JobDashboardView.as_view(), name='job')
```

I attempted to do the following for dashes:

```
url(r'^jobs/(?P<job_number>\w+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+))/$', JobDashboardView.as_view(), name='job')
```

But it did not work. Any suggestions and if this is even possible?

Clarification of the example job numbers accepted:

-13000

-13000-W1

-13000W1

-A13000

Comment: So, basically it can be any combination of letters/digits/dashes? Can you give some negative examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a character set containing the class `\w` and `-`:

```
url(r'^jobs/(?P<job_number>[\w-]+)/$', JobDashboardView.as_view(), name='job')
```